# Does formsflow.ai support authentication with social media platforms like Google?

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

I have installed the latest version of formsflow.ai : v4.0.3. All components are up, and logging I have noticed the formsflow.ai supports only username and password method by default when logging into react component.

[image]

I was curious to know if formsflow.ai support authentication to be used with single sign-on with Platforms like Google, Facebook, Github etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible as in formsflow.ai we  use keycloak for authentication . One of the strong points in favour of Keycloak adoption is the fact that you can setup social signin for your application with a few clicks, no coding requirements needed. Keycloak supports out-of-the box an extensive list of social networks: Google, Github, Facebook, Linkedin, Microsoft, Twitter and many other providers. It's even flexible enough to support the integration of any OpenId Connect or SAML 2.0 provider.